# How to count the amount of input of test scores in Python?

Tags: python

"My local school district requires an application to compare the average score of boys in a certain test with that of girls. Write an interactive application in Python to display a simple menu to the user. Have them pick a choice for boy (b), girl (g), or quit (q) to quit the program. The program should keep looping until the user chooses to quit. This application will use loops and conditions to accomplish the task. Your program should output the average boy score and average girl score. Your Python program should accept data input by the user. Your program should allow an arbitrary number of boy scores and girl scores, terminated when the user inputs a ‘q’."

*This program isn't running properly and I am unsure where I am going wrong.

This is what I have so far:

```
bscore = 0
gscore = 0
gtotal = 0
btotal = 0
baverage = 0
gaverage = 0
bcount = 0
gcount = 0
gen = 0

while(gen != "q"):
    gen = input("Please enter the scores for Boy(b), Girl(g) or Quit(q): ")
    if(gen == "b"):
        bscore = int(input("Boy score: "))
        bcount += 1
        btotal = btotal + bscore
        baverage = btotal/bcount
    elif(gen == "g"):
        gscore = int(input("Girl score: "))
        gcount += 1
        gtotal = gtotal + gscore
        gaverage = gtotal/gcount
    else:
        gen = input("Boy (b), Girl (g) or Quit (q): ")

print("Boy average is: ", baverage)
print("Girl average is: ", gaverage)
```

updated:

```
bscore = 0
gscore = 0
gtotal = 0
btotal = 0
baverage = 0
gaverage = 0
bcount = 0
gcount = 0

gen = input("Boy(b), Girl(g) or Quit(q): ")

while(gen != "q"):

    if(gen == "b"):
        bscore = int(input("Boy score: "))
        bcount += 1
        btotal = btotal + bscore

    elif(gen == "g"):
        gscore = int(input("Girl score: "))
        gcount += 1
        gtotal = gtotal + gscore

    gen = input("Boy (b), Girl (g) or Quit (q): ")

baverage = btotal/float(bcount)
gaverage = gtotal/float(gcount)

print("Boy average is: ", baverage)
print("Girl average is: ", gaverage)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's the question? :) Does your code not work? Raises an error?

Comment: Sorry about that! Thanks for the welcome! "SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier"

Comment: You're missing a bracket: `bscore = int(input("Boy score: ")` and the same for the `gscore` line.

Comment: I fixed said error, thank you!! I am still unsure where I am going wrong in this program running correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from few of the syntax errors, you need to declare your variables outside the `while` loop because they get reset to *0* each time you ask the user about *boy* or a *girl*:

Your code might look like this after fixing the logic

```
# Declare your variables outside the while loop here

bscore = 0
gscore = 0
gtotal = 0
btotal = 0
baverage = 0
gaverage = 0
bcount = 0
gcount = 0

# Ask the user for input

gen = input("Boy (b), Girl (g) or Quit (q): ")

while(gen != "q"):

    if(gen == "b"):
        bscore = int(input("Boy score: "))
        bcount += 1
        btotal = btotal + bscore

    elif(gen == "g"):
        gscore = int(input("Girl score: "))
        gcount += 1
        gtotal = gtotal + gscore

    # Ask the user if he wants another entry

    gen = input("Boy (b), Girl (g) or Quit (q): ")

# The average should only be calculated one time when user stops the program
# Therefore calculate average scores outside the while loop

baverage = btotal/float(bcount)
gaverage = gtotal/float(gcount)
print("Boy average is: ", baverage)
print("Girl average is: ", gaverage)
```

Comment: This is great- thank you! I am still reaching an error, specifically in the boy score region. I am wondering if I need to place the gen=input("Boy (b), Girl (g) or Quit (q): ") in the boy loop as well?

Comment: I am not getting any error, what is your python version?

Comment: If you have python 2.7, use 
```gen = raw_input("Boy (b), Girl (g) or Quit (q): ")```

Answer (score 0):

You might have placed ll.3-10 (where you set a lot of vars to be 0) inside of the loop, while it looks like you wanted to place them up front, so they only execute once and don't reset your stats every iteration of the loop.